# the topological realization of simplicial complex

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Definition I.18. The topological realisation $|K|$ of an abstract simplicial complex $ K = (V, Σ)$ is the space obtained by the following procedure:

(i) For each $σ ∈ Σ$, take a copy of the standard $n$-simplex, where $n + 1$ is the number of elements of $σ$. Denote this simplex by $∆σ$. Label its vertices with the elements of $σ$.

(ii) Whenever $σ ⊂ τ ∈ Σ$, identify $∆σ$ with a subset of $∆τ$ , via the face inclusion which sends the elements of $σ$ to the corresponding elements of $τ$.

http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lackenby/tg050908.pdf   page 10

It claims that $|K|$ is the union of the interiors of its simplices and the interiors are disjoint.

For $V = \{1,2,3\}$, $Σ = \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}$ (Example I.19 on page 9)

It is connected by standard 1-simplex which are lines sitting in $\mathbb R^2$, if I am right, they do not really have any interior. Then how can $|K|$ be the union of its interior?

Edit: After a second thought, if the topology is coming from the subspace topology on simplices then it has an interior.

Comment: The interiors to which they refer are the *relative interiors*, much as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior

Comment: Can I simply view it as the subspace topology on the simplex? @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: No, because the interior of a simplex when you view it as a subspace is the whole simplex!

Comment: I see, so in this case it will exclude the endpoints. @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: But what if I consider the two diagonals of a square. Their interiors will intersect each other which is a contradiction. What is wrong? @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your space consists only of $1$-simplices and $0$-simplices. While $|K|$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^2$, that is not part of the construction, so the interiors of each simplex are the interiors of the edges $\{a,b\}$, which are one dimensional spaces, and each vertex $\{a\}$, which are zero dimensional.

Comment: But in the text the 1-simplices are defined to be in $R^2$, shouldn't its topology be inherent from $R^2$?

Comment: Just after the definition of the $n$-simplex, there is a careful definition of the interior of the $n$-simplex. (page 8)

Comment: One more question, it claims that a $|K|$ is always the disjoint union of the interior of its simplices. But if I consider the diagonal of a square, they intersect with each other. What is wrong?

Comment: If you want to build the boundary of a square with its diagonals as a simplicial complex, you have to put a vertex at the center of the square, right where the diagonals would otherwise intersect.

Comment: Why can't I just connect the diagonal points with a 1-simplex?

Comment: You could, but the two diagonals wouldn't touch each other.If you want to force them to touch, you *must* add the middle vertex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37513/discussion-between-keith-and-alex-s).